# Unable to create order from admin in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

[image]

Here is server error log:

> [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 14406] [client xxx.2x1.4x.xxx:21633] AH01071:
>   Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument
>   1 passed to
>   Magento\Payment\Gateway\Data\Quote\QuoteAdapter::__construct() must
>   implement interface Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface, null given,
>   called in
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
>   on line 111 and defined in
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-payment/Gateway/Data/Quote/QuoteAdapter.php:32\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111):
>   Magento\Payment\Gateway\Data\Quote\QuoteAdapter->__construct(NULL,
>   Object(Magento\Payment\Gateway\Data\Quote\AddressAdapterFactory))\n#1
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Payment...',
>   Array)\n#2
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Payment...',...\n',
>   referer:
>   https://magentosite.com/admin/sales/order/index/key/9bafd2f5e462f32d65756b10f575c2e6e76a64ddd16f255487d2a90a081fbb7e/

Comment: Run commands : php bin/magento setup:di:compile,
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy and check again

Answer (score 0):

Please check you construct once , First argument expecting instance of Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface.

For example :

```
 protected $_cart;
    public function __construct(
        Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $cart,
    ) {
        $this->_cart = $cart;
        parent::__construct($this->_cart);
    }
```

It will help you to resolve your issue.